# Jquery Draggable Throwing error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-draggable

Hi following is my code Snippet. What i am trying to do is that i want to find `img` within the `image_div` and attach `draggable` event to it.

```
    $(function() {
        jQuery('#image_div').each({
       $(this).find('img').draggable({revert: true});)};
    });
```

Above Code Throws me following error

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id//$(this).find('img').draggable({revert: true});
```

Comment: can you make a Jsfiddle ppls?

Comment: never done it, but lets try it anyway

Comment: @MarkWalters: i updated code, i just had a type while pasting it.

Comment: @JFit: this is some what close to what my data representation is 
http://jsfiddle.net/FCjr5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're overcomplicating it..

Here is your updated fiddle..
http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/FCjr5/1/

Selectors in JQuery always return an array of objects. you do not need to use a loop to iterate through them to create events for each one.. for example, 5 buttons with the same class "buttonClass" have the same click event:  `$('.buttonClass').click(function () { ..... });`

Comment: Whups sorry, removed your revert.. add `$('img').draggable({ revert: true });`

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `.each()` on a single element. Your selector `$('#image_div');` will return the one div element. Use `.find()` directly on this element to look within it and find all `img` tags. Your code should look like this.

```
$(function() {
    jQuery('#image_div').find('img').draggable({ revert: true });
});
```

Also in your fiddle, your `img` tags weren't closed and you need to reference jQuery ui on the left hand side for `.draggable()` to work

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Xe6L9/) is a working fiddle.

Comment: you sorted the problem but `@JF it` provided the solution, so upvote for you and accepted for him